# Extjs4.2 - Get rowIndex of a selected row

Tags: grid, grouping, extjs4.2

I have set up a grid panel with groupingsummary (tried grouping feature also - no luck) feature and actioncolumn [for deleting and editing records]. I'm wrestling a couple of days to get row index but to no avail.

Without the groupingsummary feature the actioncolumn works as it should, i can edit or delete a row by clinking the action icons using the following code to select a row:

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex) {
    rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);

    rowId = rec.get('rowId');
    rowName = rec.get('rowName');
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then i execute an Ajax request to the server for the corresponding action [edit, delete].
How do i select a row in a grid with groupingsummary feature? Is it a bug?

Comment: What isn't working about the groupingsummary feature? We need a lot more details to be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, the "actioncolumn" is not working. Cannot get row index when using grouping feature

Comment: So is `rowIndex` undefined? What is it's value when the function you show in your question executes?

Comment: Yes, it returns undefined